# Issue with Androids native video fullscreen

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a very simple site with an embedded video from Vimeo. However it seems that when playing the video with an Android device it starts in fullscreen. That would be fine if its not for my previous content still showing above the content. I've tried many kind of z-index fixes, without any luck. Anyone who have a smart fix for this issue? This is the code:

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #a6c0fe 0%, #f68084 100%);*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /*background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);*/
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 3rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;

  /*background-size: 10000px 100%;*/
  /*animation: bg 150s linear infinite;*/
}

/*@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 10000px;
  }
}*/

#logo{
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  opacity: .9;
  animation: logo 500ms ease-in-out both;
  animation-delay: 300ms;

}

.tc{
  text-align: center;
}

#content{
  /*padding: 20px;*/
  margin:0 -10px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


ul{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  /*display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;*/
}

li{
  list-style: none;
  background: white;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  /*height: 565px;*/
  /*flex-basis:300px;*/
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

h2{
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
  color:#333;
}

li img{
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li:hover{
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4);*/
  filter:saturate(.2);
}

.links{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.links img{
  width: 30px;
  margin: 25px 0 20px;
  opacity: .6;
}
.links .apple{
    margin-top: 20px
}

.links img:hover{
  opacity: .8;
}

/*@media all and (max-width: 9500px) and (min-width: 2000px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 5 - 20px);
  }
}*/

/*@media all and (max-width: 1999px) and (min-width: 1400px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 5 - 20px);
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}*/

@media all and (max-width: 9999px) and (min-width: 959px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 3 - 20px);
  }

  li:nth-child(4),li:nth-child(5){
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 2 - 20px);
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}


@media all and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 769px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 2 - 20px);
  }

  li:nth-child(5){
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 1 - 20px);
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 770px) and (min-width: 1px){
  body{padding: .5rem;}
  #logo{width: 80%;margin-top: 30px;}

  .videoWrapper{
    margin: 0!important;
    padding-top: 0!important;
  }

  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 1 - 20px);
  }

  h2{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}

/*@media all and (max-width: 3500px) and (min-width: 1px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 3 - 20px);
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 3500px) and (min-width: 1px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 3 - 20px);
  }
}*/



#video{
  animation: fadeIn 500ms ease-in-out both;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.videoWrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 padding-top: 25px;
 height: 0;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: calc(100% - 20px);
 height: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

#contact{
  background: white;
  margin: 50px 10px;;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

h1{
  font-size: 16px;

}

#contact img{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.name{
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.subtitle{
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color:#777;
}

.mail{
  font-size: 16px;
}

a{color:#333;text-decoration: none;}



li{
  animation: ar 500ms ease-in-out both;
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}

  li:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: 550ms;
}
  li:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: 600ms;
}
  li:nth-child(4){
  animation-delay: 650ms;
}
  li:nth-child(5){
  animation-delay: 700ms;
}


@keyframes ar {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0);
}

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}


@keyframes logo {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>COPENHAGEN RECORDS S/S 2017 COLLECTION
</title>
  <meta name="description" content="COPENHAGEN RECORDS S/S 2017 COLLECTION">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>


<div id="content">

<div class="tc">
  <img id="logo" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/logowhite.svg">
</div>

<div id="video">
  <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/208457219" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>


<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Alex Vargas</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/vargas.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/alexvargasofficial"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com/alexvargasmusic"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/alexvargasofficial"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/3kdU3J8t1HUPZqFyScP8SF"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/dk/artist/alex-vargas/id207308428"><img class="apple" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/apple.svg"></a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Maximillian</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/maximillian.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/maximillianmusic"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maximillian_rasmussen/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0CgEdC-nJuh4FR6QJdo_1A"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <!-- <a href="#"><img src="img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img class="apple" src="img/apple.svg"></a> -->
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>SAVEUS</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/saveus.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/saveusofficial/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/saveus/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/saveusVEVO"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/2rR0cafJvL0JVTC8E2qIqt"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/dk/artist/saveus/id961149212?l=da"><img class="apple" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/apple.svg"></a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Hedegaard</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/hedegaard.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DJHEDEGAARD"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/Hedegaarddk/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/HedegaardVEVO"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/2ZuweXv0TkfsidZOLZZoM2 "><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/dk/artist/hedegaard/id406495070?l=das"><img class="apple" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/apple.svg"></a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Scarlet Pleasure</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/scarlet.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/scarletpleasure/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/Scarletpleasure/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/ScarletPleasureVEVO"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <a href=" https://play.spotify.com/artist/7wrulS1dfanckBnoxxEuS6?play=true&utm_source=open.spotify.com&utm_medium=open"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/dk/artist/scarlet-pleasure/id823560885?l=da"><img class="apple" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/apple.svg"></a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>




<div id="contact">
<h1>For more details please contact Copenhagen Records</h1>
<!-- <img src="img/torben.jpg"> -->
<p class="name">Torben Ravn</p>
<p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
<a href="mailto:torben@copenhagenrecords.dk"><p class="mail">Mail: torben@copenhagenrecords.dk</p></a>

</div>







</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #a6c0fe 0%, #f68084 100%);*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /*background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);*/
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 3rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;

  /*background-size: 10000px 100%;*/
  /*animation: bg 150s linear infinite;*/
}

/*@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 10000px;
  }
}*/

#logo{
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  opacity: .9;
  animation: logo 500ms ease-in-out both;
  animation-delay: 300ms;

}

.tc{
  text-align: center;
}

#content{
  /*padding: 20px;*/
  margin:0 -10px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


ul{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  /*display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;*/
}

li{
  list-style: none;
  background: white;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  /*height: 565px;*/
  /*flex-basis:300px;*/
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

h2{
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
  color:#333;
}

li img{
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li:hover{
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4);*/
  filter:saturate(.2);
}

.links{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.links img{
  width: 30px;
  margin: 25px 0 20px;
  opacity: .6;
}
.links .apple{
    margin-top: 20px
}

.links img:hover{
  opacity: .8;
}

/*@media all and (max-width: 9500px) and (min-width: 2000px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 5 - 20px);
  }
}*/

/*@media all and (max-width: 1999px) and (min-width: 1400px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 5 - 20px);
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}*/

@media all and (max-width: 9999px) and (min-width: 959px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 3 - 20px);
  }

  li:nth-child(4),li:nth-child(5){
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 2 - 20px);
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}


@media all and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 769px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 2 - 20px);
  }

  li:nth-child(5){
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 1 - 20px);
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 770px) and (min-width: 1px){
  body{padding: .5rem;}
  #logo{width: 80%;margin-top: 30px;}

  .videoWrapper{
    margin: 0!important;
    padding-top: 0!important;
  }

  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 1 - 20px);
  }

  h2{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}

/*@media all and (max-width: 3500px) and (min-width: 1px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 3 - 20px);
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 3500px) and (min-width: 1px){
  li{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% * 1 / 3 - 20px);
  }
}*/



#video{
  animation: fadeIn 500ms ease-in-out both;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.videoWrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 padding-top: 25px;
 height: 0;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: calc(100% - 20px);
 height: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

#contact{
  background: white;
  margin: 50px 10px;;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

h1{
  font-size: 16px;

}

#contact img{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.name{
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.subtitle{
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color:#777;
}

.mail{
  font-size: 16px;
}

a{color:#333;text-decoration: none;}



li{
  animation: ar 500ms ease-in-out both;
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}

  li:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: 550ms;
}
  li:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: 600ms;
}
  li:nth-child(4){
  animation-delay: 650ms;
}
  li:nth-child(5){
  animation-delay: 700ms;
}


@keyframes ar {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0);
}

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}


@keyframes logo {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>COPENHAGEN RECORDS S/S 2017 COLLECTION
</title>
  <meta name="description" content="COPENHAGEN RECORDS S/S 2017 COLLECTION">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>


<div id="content">

<div class="tc">
  <img id="logo" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/logowhite.svg">
</div>

<div id="video">
  <div class="videoWrapper">
 <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/208457219" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>  </div>
</div>


<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Alex Vargas</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/vargas.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/alexvargasofficial"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com/alexvargasmusic"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/alexvargasofficial"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/3kdU3J8t1HUPZqFyScP8SF"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/dk/artist/alex-vargas/id207308428"><img class="apple" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/apple.svg"></a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Maximillian</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/maximillian.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/maximillianmusic"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maximillian_rasmussen/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0CgEdC-nJuh4FR6QJdo_1A"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <!-- <a href="#"><img src="img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img class="apple" src="img/apple.svg"></a> -->
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>SAVEUS</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/saveus.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/saveusofficial/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/saveus/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/saveusVEVO"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/2rR0cafJvL0JVTC8E2qIqt"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/dk/artist/saveus/id961149212?l=da"><img class="apple" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/apple.svg"></a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Hedegaard</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/hedegaard.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DJHEDEGAARD"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/Hedegaarddk/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/HedegaardVEVO"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/2ZuweXv0TkfsidZOLZZoM2 "><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/dk/artist/hedegaard/id406495070?l=das"><img class="apple" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/apple.svg"></a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Scarlet Pleasure</h2>
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/scarlet.jpg">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/scarletpleasure/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/facebook.svg"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/Scarletpleasure/"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/instagram.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/ScarletPleasureVEVO"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/youtube.svg"></a>
      <a href=" https://play.spotify.com/artist/7wrulS1dfanckBnoxxEuS6?play=true&utm_source=open.spotify.com&utm_medium=open"><img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/spotify.svg"></a>
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/dk/artist/scarlet-pleasure/id823560885?l=da"><img class="apple" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/cphrec/img/apple.svg"></a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>




<div id="contact">
<h1>For more details please contact Copenhagen Records</h1>
<!-- <img src="img/torben.jpg"> -->
<p class="name">Torben Ravn</p>
<p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
<a href="mailto:torben@copenhagenrecords.dk"><p class="mail">Mail: torben@copenhagenrecords.dk</p></a>

</div>







</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @amal. Which parts have you changed? I've made some changes to the original code, so can no longer copy-paste :l

Comment: i have made changes in iframe tag